# App is crashing while using SWRevealViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, swrevealviewcontroller

I am using **SWRevealViewController** for **Slide Out Menu** for an application in which ***slide out menu starts only from the Home Screen*** after Sign Up button is pressed in SignUp page(i.e. running the application for the first time).

When the app is running for the second time it is suppose to go directly to the Home Screen,but the app is crashing, and I am getting crash log in **ViewController**.

```
_barBtnMenu.target = self.revealViewController;
    _barBtnMenu.action = @selector(revealToggle:);
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:self.revealViewController.panGestureRecognizer];
```

> NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:'-[__NSArrayM
>   insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil.

For app's first time run I am using ***Present Modally Segue*** from Sign Up button.

In **SWRevealViewController**

```
- (SWRevealViewController*)revealViewController
{
    UIViewController *parent = self;
    Class revealClass = [SWRevealViewController class];
    while ( nil != (parent = [parent parentViewController]) && ![parent isKindOfClass:revealClass] ) {}
    return (id)parent;
}
```

While running it for the first time 
**parent** is returning a value but for the second run it is returning **nil**

If anyone could help me in solving the issue.
Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    NSString *savedValue = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
                            stringForKey:@"email"];
    if (savedValue != nil) {

        UIStoryboard *storyboard = self.window.rootViewController.storyboard;
        ViewController *viewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"viewController"];
        self.window.rootViewController =viewController;
        [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Sign Up screen opened");
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Share your source codes please.

Comment: How did you instantiate SWRevealViewController ? From storyboard or from your code ?

Comment: I worked it out differently ,but thanks for replying..

Comment: Your way should work but not the ideal solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the replies,

I solved it by making SignUp page as Root view

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    NSString *savedValue = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
                            stringForKey:@"email"];
    if (savedValue == nil) {
         UIStoryboard *storyboard = self.window.rootViewController.storyboard;
          SignUpViewController *signUpViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"signUpViewController"];
        self.window.rootViewController = signUpViewController;
        [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Sign Up screen closed,Hom page opened");
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to implement Autologin feature in your app

for the second launch you have to maintain a flag in Appdelegate that user is already logged in or not , if user is already logged in you have to move to the parent controller of SWRevealview from didfinishlaunchingwithoptions function in app delegate.

for that save username and password to userdefaults at login & signup

check for values in didfinishlaunchingwithoptions

if value exist move to parent of SWrevealview

Comment: Here   ViewController *viewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"viewController"];
        self.window.rootViewController =viewController;  this should be the parent of swrevealviewcontroller.